# How to exclude mock package from python coverage report using nosetests

Tags: python, mocking, code-coverage, nose, python-mock

I currently try to use the mock library to write some basic nose unittests in python.

After finishing some basic example I now tried to use `nosetests --with-coverage` and now I have the mock package and the package I tried to 'mock away' are shown in the coverage report. Is there a possibility to exclude these?

Here is the class I want to test:

```
from imaplib import IMAP4

class ImapProxy:
    def __init__(self, host):
        self._client = IMAP4(host)
```

And the testcase:
    from mock import patch

```
from ImapProxy import ImapProxy

class TestImap:
    def test_connect(self):
        with patch('ImapProxy.IMAP4') as imapMock:
            proxy = ImapProxy("testhost")
            imapMock.assert_called_once_with("testhost")
```

I now get the following output for `nosetests --with-coverage`

```
.
Name         Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------
ImapProxy        4      0   100%   
imaplib        675    675     0%   23-1519
mock          1240    810    35%   [ a lot of lines]
```

Is there any way to exclude the mock package and the imaplib package **without** having to manually whitelisting all but those packages by `--cover-package=PACKAGE`

Thanks to Ned Batchelder I now know about the .coveragerc file, thanks for that!

I created a .coveragerc file with the following content:

```
[report]
omit = *mock*
```

Now my output for mock in the coverage report is:

```
mock                     1240   1240     0%   16-2356
```

It does not cover the mock package any longer but still shows it in the report.

I use Coverage.py, version 3.5.2 if this is any help.

Comment: Try to erase previous data with `--cover-erase`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Create a .coveragerc file that excludes what you don't want in the report: http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html

Comment: Could you have a look at the information I added in my question? I am not sure whether it is an error on my side or if omit in the [report] block is not working correctly.

Comment: I am facing a similar problem, and created a `coveragerc` file which contains inclusions and omissions. However, nose does not seem to consider it and proceeds to run coverage on all of Python's libraries (despite `cover_pylib` being set to `False` in the configuration file). Any idea how to make coveragerc work with nose?

Comment: Ok now after Thomas E Jenkins gave another answer I retested it and the current coverage version does not have this behavior any longer.

Comment: So there is no way to include the .coveragerc file any longer? How does one go about excluding items from a test?

Comment: @digitaldavenyc coverage.py still supports .coveragerc files.  If you are having a problem, let's start another thread.

Answer (score 14):

In your .coveragerc move your `omit` entry from the `[report]` section to the `[run]` section.

Comment: Exactly. `[report]` suppresses per-file reporting but does not alter the % calculations. `[run]` works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar situation testing a series of sub-packages within my main package directory.  I was running `nosetests` from within the top directory of my module and `Mock` and other libraries were included in the coverage report.  I tried using `--cover-module my_package` in nosetests, but then the subpackages were not included.

Running the following solved my problem:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-package ../my_package
```

So, *if* all the code that you want to test is in the same directory, *then* you can get coverage for it alone by specifying the module path to `nosetests`.  This avoids the need to whitelist each of the submodules individually.

(Python 2.7.6, coverage 4.0.3, nose 1.3.7)