# How to ignore / omit / exclude files during test coverage?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

In order to get 100% test coverage, I need to ignore some file(s) in python.

I searched the web and I found `nosetests` which I don't want to use.

I also found that I can edit my `.coveragerc` file and omit files and functions, when running my tests using intellij (with unittest framework), it didn't manage to use `.coveragerc` file.

Any idea how to ignore / omit / exclude files during test coverage ?

How can I run the test using this file as a parameter ?

Answer (score 22):

You can use this command in your .coveragerc file.

```
# .coveragerc
[report]
show_missing = True
omit =
    junk/*
```

You include the path of files you want to omit under the omit command, for example, I want to omit every file in the junk folder hence my use of `junk/*`.

Answer (score 3):

To add to [proton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570883/how-to-ignore-omit-exclude-files-during-test-coverage/44390141#44390141).

You can also use the `# pragma: no cover` commenting specific clauses. You can comment every clause in a file to exclude the content of the file. This is more tedious but gives you finer control if you want to partially ignore a file.

Here is a link to the coverage.py project that discuses coverage exclusion in further detail:
https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/7.0.0/excluding.html

---

I would have commented on [proton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43570883/how-to-ignore-omit-exclude-files-during-test-coverage/44390141#44390141) instead of making a new answer, but I do not have enough reputation. More so, I would have suggested an edit, but there are too many pending edits and stack-overflow will not let me add another.