# Python unittest ignore numpy

Tags: python, unit-testing, numpy, nosetests, python-unittest

I am writing python tests with unittest and running the tests from the command line with

```
 nosetests --with-coverage -x
```

When I include numpy in one of my tests it tries to test the numpy packages as well. Example output:

```
...
Name                            Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------------
CLOCK                              39     33    15%   3, 7-13, 17, 20-25, 28-47
LFU                                42      1    98%   52
LRU                                95      9    91%   12, 64, 68, 101, 115-118, 131
LRU10                              54      1    98%   68
LRU3                               54      1    98%   68
argparse                         1177   1177     0%   3-2361
cache                              86     33    62%   36-47, 86-89, 95-116
common                             87     54    38%   17, 20, 23, 28, 31-32, 35-36, 39, 42, 46, 48, 50, 52, 54, 57-64, 67-68, 72-89, 95-96, 102-107, 112-118, 123
ctypes                            341    341     0%   4-555
ctypes._endian                     35     35     0%   4-64
numpy                              56     56     0%   107-197
numpy.__config__                   27     27     0%   3-32
numpy._import_tools               224    224     0%   1-348
numpy.add_newdocs                 275    275     0%   11-7459
numpy.compat                        8      8     0%   11-20
numpy.compat._inspect             106    106     0%   8-221
numpy.compat.py3k                  57     57     0%   5-89
numpy.core                         56     56     0%   1-74
numpy.core._internal              350    350     0%   7-570
numpy.core._methods                72     72     0%   6-130
numpy.core.arrayprint             354    354     0%   6-752
numpy.core.defchararray           364    364     0%   18-2686
numpy.core.fromnumeric            310    310     0%   4-2918
numpy.core.function_base           24     24     0%   1-173
numpy.core.getlimits              132    132     0%   4-306
numpy.core.info                     3      3     0%   84-87
numpy.core.machar                 186    186     0%   8-338
numpy.core.memmap                  83     83     0%   1-305
numpy.core.numeric                523    523     0%   1-2730
numpy.core.numerictypes           381    381     0%   83-1035
numpy.core.records                356    356     0%   37-808
numpy.core.shape_base              50     50     0%   1-277
numpy.ctypeslib                   187    187     0%   52-426
numpy.fft                           7      7     0%   1-11
numpy.fft.fftpack                 109    109     0%   33-1119
numpy.fft.helper                   51     51     0%   5-223
numpy.fft.info                      2      2     0%   177-179
numpy.lib                          38     38     0%   1-45
numpy.lib._datasource             178    178     0%   34-656
numpy.lib._iotools                372    372     0%   4-874
numpy.lib.arraypad                383    383     0%   6-1469
numpy.lib.arraysetops              98     98     0%   27-450
numpy.lib.arrayterator             72     72     0%   10-224
numpy.lib.financial               112    112     0%   11-735
numpy.lib.format                  178    178     0%   137-614
numpy.lib.function_base           889    889     0%   1-3555
numpy.lib.index_tricks            250    250     0%   1-849
numpy.lib.info                      3      3     0%   148-151
numpy.lib.nanfunctions            138    138     0%   17-838
numpy.lib.npyio                   729    729     0%   1-1899
numpy.lib.polynomial              386    386     0%   5-1266
numpy.lib.scimath                  55     55     0%   18-560
numpy.lib.shape_base              200    200     0%   1-834
numpy.lib.stride_tricks            48     48     0%   8-121
numpy.lib.twodim_base             116    116     0%   4-929
numpy.lib.type_check              104    104     0%   4-605
numpy.lib.ufunclike                23     23     0%   6-177
numpy.lib.utils                   517    517     0%   1-1134
numpy.linalg                        6      6     0%   45-54
numpy.linalg.info                   2      2     0%   35-37
numpy.linalg.linalg               530    530     0%   11-2131
numpy.ma                           15     15     0%   39-58
numpy.ma.core                    2324   2324     0%   23-7243
numpy.ma.extras                   610    610     0%   11-1885
numpy.matrixlib                     6      6     0%   4-12
numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix         286    286     0%   1-1094
numpy.polynomial                   11     11     0%   16-29
numpy.polynomial.chebyshev        432    432     0%   88-2015
numpy.polynomial.hermite          382    382     0%   60-1750
numpy.polynomial.hermite_e        379    379     0%   60-1746
numpy.polynomial.laguerre         379    379     0%   60-1742
numpy.polynomial.legendre         386    386     0%   84-1768
numpy.polynomial.polynomial       302    302     0%   56-1493
numpy.polynomial.polytemplate       4      4     0%   12-17
numpy.polynomial.polyutils         67     67     0%   34-384
numpy.random                       13     13     0%   89-114
numpy.random.info                   3      3     0%   85-89
numpy.version                       7      7     0%   3-10
statistics                         19      2    89%   24-25
statistics.countingghost           84     44    48%   43-60, 66-69, 75-80, 83-89, 93-104, 107, 110-113
statistics.rounder                 89     17    81%   29, 40, 70-83, 112-113
-------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                           17686  17145     3%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 3.279s

OK
```

How can I correctly ignore the numpy tests with the -I -m or -e parameters? 
I could pipe this to grep -v numpy but that is not cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nose plugin specifically for the task - [nose-exclude](https://bitbucket.org/kgrandis/nose-exclude/src):

> nose-exclude is a Nose plugin that allows you to easily specify
>   directories to be excluded from testing.

Another option is to specify `omit` [configuration parameter](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/config.html) in `.coveragerc` file:

> omit (multi-string): a list of filename patterns, the files to leave
>   out of measurement or reporting.

See also: [How to exclude mock package from python coverage report using nosetests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12187106/how-to-exclude-mock-package-from-python-coverage-report-using-nosetests)

Comment: Thanks that worked! Added a .coveragerc file to the project directory with the following text (newline after the [report]): 
`[report]
omit = *numpy*`

Answer (score 1):

You can also specify which package you'd like to run tests for when you call nose with the `--cover-package` flag.

#### E.g.

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=the-name-of-your-package -x
```